# Adding GroupBox into VB program causes the program to crash

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, groupbox

So here's a head scratcher. Recently I finished a program in VB that have several GroupBox to place my buttons in. And during testing in my PC everything worked out fine.

But when I want to test it on user PC, the program immediately pop up a "The program is not responding" message and stops process immediately without even showing the form. The user PC does not have Visual Basic 2010 installed.

After experimenting further I found out that the GroupBox were the cause, when I removed them the program can run in user PC fine.

So yeah... Till now I don't know why GroupBox doesn't want to play well like this. Is this a common problem in general?

P.S. I don't know if this is the right place to ask this. If not please let me know and I'll remove this question. Thanks.

Comment: Not the GroupBox, maybe the way you access objects inside these containers. You didn't post any code, so it's difficult to say what might go wrong.

Comment: You should ALWAYS be handling the `UnhandledException` event of the application and logging any exceptions there that you haven't explicitly caught anywhere else. It also means that you can notify the user that an issue has occurred and shutdown gracefully.